# Show that if $m$ and $n$ are integers and $a$ and $b$ are elements from a ring, then $(m \cdot a) ( n \cdot b) = (mn) \cdot (ab)$

Tags: solution-verification, field-theory, induction

> Show that if $m$ and $n$ are integers and $a$ and $b$ are elements from a ring, then $(m \cdot a) ( n \cdot b) = (mn) \cdot (ab)$
>
> Source:Gallian 7th ed Pg. 243, Q.15

Consider $P(n)$ to be the statement that  $\forall m \in M$ , $(m \cdot a) ( n \cdot b)=(mn) \cdot (ab)$ is true

##### Induction:

1. **Base case:** $P(1) = (m \cdot a)( 1 \cdot b) = (m \cdot a)(b)$

   Let $P(m)$ be the statement that $(m \cdot a)(b) = (m \cdot 1) (ab)$, then:

   1.1. **Base case** : $(1 \cdot a)(b) =(ab)=  (1 \cdot 1)(ab)$

   1.2. **Proving $P(m+1)$ from $P(m)$**: $ (m+1)a \cdot b= (m)a \cdot b + (1) a\cdot b= (m \cdot 1) ab + 1 a \cdot b= m(a \cdot b) + a \cdot b = (m+1) (a \cdot b)$
2. **Proving $n+1$th case from $nth$**:

   $P(n+1) = (  m \cdot a) \left( (n+1) \cdot b \right) = (m \cdot a) \left( n \cdot b + 1 \cdot b\right)= (m\cdot a)( n \cdot b) + ( m \cdot a) (b)= (mn) \cdot (a b) + (m) \cdot (ab)= (mn+m) \cdot (ab)=\left( (m+1)n\right) \cdot (ab)$

Remark: I have used the result in the sub induction to simplify the last equality in the above.

I am not sure how to extend the above proof to $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

Could I get some one check my work so far, and, explain how I could finish it?

Comment: Do you mean “for all $m\in \mathbb Z$“ in your statement of $P(n)?$ because the notation $P(n)$ implies an unbound $n.$

Comment: Also, your induction technically only proves it for positive $n.$ You need to prove it form $n\leq 0,$ too.

Comment: Oops, I mistook the statement as a simpler one when proving. Is there anyway to extend my proof to integers?

Comment: Well, my first point was, “for all $n$“ should be “for all $m,$” whether you are proving for $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps show the simpler statements
$$\tag1(n\cdot a)\cdot b=n\cdot(a\cdot b)$$
and
$$\tag2a\cdot(n\cdot b)=n\cdot(a\cdot b)$$
and
$$\tag3m\cdot(n\cdot a)=(mn)\cdot a$$
(which you may already have done).

Then use these to see
$$(m\cdot a)\cdot(n\cdot b)
\stackrel{(1)}=m\cdot(a\cdot(n\cdot b))
\stackrel{(2)}=m\cdot(n\cdot(a\cdot b))
\stackrel{(3)}=(mn)\cdot(a\cdot b)$$